# Compare Values in TreeMap

Tags: java

I have some logs stored in `Map<Date, String>` where String denotes an Action, and Date represents the date on which the action is performed;

```
  Sat Jan 11 06:00:00 IST 2014=Read User
  Fri May 15 05:45:56 IST 2015=Update User
  Tue Nov 21 07:23:00 IST 2017=Create User  
  Tue Nov 21 08:34:00 IST 2017=Delete User
  Thu Nov 23 11:34:00 IST 2017=Create User
  Mon Jul 30 10:34:20 IST 2018=Delete User
```

My requirement is that for a log, create a new map where action would be Old Action + Action of same value which are below it in the old Map.

Example Output:

```
Sat Jan 11 06:00:00 IST 2014=Read User
Fri May 15 05:45:56 IST 2015=Update User
Tue Nov 21 07:23:00 IST 2017=Create User  Create User [Thu Nov 23 11:34:00 
                                                                IST 2017 ]
Tue Nov 21 08:34:00 IST 2017=Delete User  Delete User [Mon Jul 30 10:34:20 
                                                                IST 2018 ]
Thu Nov 23 11:34:00 IST 2017=Create User
Mon Jul 30 10:34:20 IST 2018=Delete User
```

My Solution:

```
Map<Date, String> auditMap = new TreeMap<Date, String>();
Map<Date, String> auditMap2 = new TreeMap<Date, String>();

Collection<String> ls = auditMap.values();
Object[] arr = ls.toArray();
int count = 1;

for(Map.Entry<Date, String> d: auditMap.entrySet()) {               
    String da = d.getValue();

    for (int i = count ; i<arr.length ; i++) {
        if(d.getValue().equals(arr[i])) {
            da = da.concat("  ").concat((String) arr[i]).concat(" [" + auditMap.keySet().toArray()[i] +" ]");                       
        }
    }

    count++;
    auditMap2.put(d.getKey(), da);
}

for (Map.Entry<Date, String> d1: auditMap2.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(d1);
}
```

How can I make my code more efficient as I am using two for loops. Is there anyway I can reduce my code ?

Comment: in output why you have duplicate entries for create user and delete with same.. is this the correct output you are looking for or something else like you want to have all dates for a particular action (create or delete etc) at same place?

Comment: The output is correct. The idea is suppose, I am reading Create User from map, then I must look for other 'create user' below it. If it is there, then Add both the actions. If not, then put the original value in the new map. Please see my map below computation and after computation.

Comment: Do you want to add **all** following occurrences or just the first next one?

Comment: Add all the occurrences below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Linear approach**

The minimal achievable complexity is `O(n)`, with `n` the size of the audit map, since you need to traverse each audit action at least once.

Your algorithm is basically quadratic (`O(n^2)`).

If a better complexity is required, you need to make sure to iterate over each of element of `auditMap` once:

```
Map<Date, String> auditMap = new TreeMap<Date, String>();
Map<String, AggregatedAction> aggregatedActions = new HashMap<>();

// Traverse each action once.
for (Map.Entry<Date, String> e : auditMap.entrySet()) {
  Date date = e.getKey();
  String action = e.getValue();

  // If the number of types of actions is small, the lookup in the 
  // aggregatedActions map can be estimated to be O(1).
  AggregatedAction aggregated = aggregatedActions.get(action);
  if (aggregated == null) {
    aggregated = new AggregatedAction(date, action);
    aggregatedActions.put(action, aggregated);

  } else {
    aggregated.append(date);
  }
}

// If you want a copy of your original map,
// otherwise you could just update it in place.
Map<Date, String> auditMap2 = new LinkedHashMap<Date, String>(auditMap);

// O(b) where b is the number of types of actions.
for (AggregatedAction action : aggregatedActions.values()) {
  auditMap2.put(action.firstOccurence, action.concatenatedAction.toString());
}
```

Where `AggregatedAction` is defined as:

```
public static final class AggregatedAction {
  private final StringBuilder concatenatedAction = new StringBuilder();
  private final String action;
  private final Date firstOccurence;

  public AggregatedAction(Date firstOccurence, String action) {
    this.firstOccurence = firstOccurence;
    this.action = action;
    concatenatedAction.append(action);
  }

  public void append(Date nextOccurence) {
    concatenatedAction.append(" ").append(action).append(" [").append(nextOccurence).append(" ]");
  }
}
```

**Complexity analysis**

With

- `n` Size of the `audit` map
- `b` Size of the `aggregatedActions` map

The code above achieves `O(n + b) = O(n)` if `b << n`.

One critical assumption made here is that the time complexity for the `append` operation is constant. This is actually not the case, because the `StringBuilder` will need to re-allocate array as its internal string grows. If the concatenation became too expensive, tough, we could think about a different construct such as a list or pre-allocate an array with an estimated size upfront, which would guarantee a constant time for each concatenation and make the `O(n)` complexity possible. But I would need to have more details about the sizes involved in your use case to see if it is worth it.

Also, copying the input map into a new `TreeMap` can yield an additional `O(nlog(n))` cost. We can solve this if we accept to use another data structure, such as a list, or a `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: I liked your idea, but the main problem is the above code searches for the occurence and it removes the remaining occurence. Check my output for reference, your code removes the last two line.

Comment: @amansaraf Are you sure? I think you keep everything because of the copy: `auditMap2 = new TreeMap<Date, String>(auditMap)`. By passing `auditMap` to the constructor of `TreeMap`, it copies all the element of `auditMap` into `auditMap2`.

Comment: Oops, I missed that point, I didn't ran your code, was just analyzing the output by seeing it. Yeah, It will copy everything along with manipulation, this looks good. Very nice way of implementation.

Comment: My only worries about this implementation is the cost of appending the `String`. If it happens to be too expensive, you could perhaps replace it with another construct (if possible) e.g. a (linked) list. But I guess you will need to merge it into a single `String` at some point anyway.

Comment: @amansaraf: Note that I replaced the second `TreeMap` (`auditMap2`) with a `LinkedHashMap` because copying `audit` into another `TreeMap` is `O(nlog(n))`, versus `O(1)` for a `LinkedHashMap`. Anyway, please note all of this may not be a concern if `n` is not "too large"! Do you know which range this value falls into?

Comment: n is not so large, using LinkedHashMap makes some sense. Thanks for explaining so many concepts into a single solution. It means a lot !!

Comment: @amansaraf Thanks, this problem was quite practical in the sense similar interrogations about double iterations _vs_ more linear approaches can be quite common. The focus on "optimal" complexity here have a bias towards _premature optimisation_, which can do more harm than good. It surely is interesting but comes with the tradeoff of increased verbosity. A solution combining both optimal algorithmic and a better operational complexity should be achievable but I can't think of one off the top of my head. Perhaps more a matter of intellectual curiosity than a practical requirement though.

Answer (score 1):

Then solution then is to store the input asa a `List<Log_Objects>` containting `Action & Data` as members. Then group it with `Action` as key and the `Time` it was done on as a Set value, using the groupingBy function. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)

Answer (score 1):

The following algorithm is another version with a `O(n²)` complexity that is more readable:

```
Map<Date, String> auditMap = new TreeMap<>();
Map<Date, String> result = new TreeMap<>();

List<Map.Entry<Date, String>> entries = Lists.newArrayList(auditMap.entrySet());
for (int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++) {
    Map.Entry<Date, String> entry = entries.get(i);

    // This SB will contain all next occurrences
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(entry.getValue());

    // Checks all the next occurrences in the iterator for equal values
    // To add them to the SB
    for (int j = i + 1; j < entries.size(); j++) {
        if (Objects.equals(entries.get(j).getValue(), entry.getValue())) {
            sb.append(" ").append(entry.getValue());
            sb.append(" [").append(entry.getKey()).append("]");
        }
    }

    // Builds the result map
    result.put(entry.getKey(), sb.toString());
}
```

### Complexity analysis:

The loop on the original map counts n items.

The nested loop then counts (n - i + 1) items which is, by turn: (n - 1), (n - 2), ..., 1 items.

The total is the sum from 1 to n, which is equal to n * (n + 1) / 2. That means the total complexity is `O(n²)`.

Comment: Didn't test it though, tell me if there is anything wrong with it.

Comment: The while (iterator.hasNext()) only takes one iterates for First Value in map. It  doesnt iterate over for the remaining values. However, I liked  your idea.

Comment: Oh that would mean that `forEachRemaining` consumes the rest... oops

Comment: Yeah. Absolutely.

Comment: I replaced the iterator then. What about this? Looks like it's still o(nlog(n)), I'm thinking about a o(n) solution.

Comment: Now that I think about it, your algorithm seems to be o(nlog(n)) too...

Comment: Can you please guide me on how did you determined complexity ?

Comment: This is actually just a prettier (and slightly better in perf because of the SB) version that your original.

Comment: But depending on your needs and estimating the number of elements you're dealing with, it up to you to say if performances is the only thing you should be looking for.

Comment: yeah, Actually it is. Thanks for clearing out my doubt and showing me a way to write a cleaner code . :)

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez "spreading false information on a community website" looks like a childish accusation. Could you elaborate on why the solution is quadratic instead? Note that the nested loop does not start from index 0.

Comment: Counting the number of iterations as `i` goes from `0` to `n` and `j` from `i + 1` to `n`: `n + (n-1) + ... + 1 = n.(n + 1) / 2`

Comment: Oh ok, I see it now, thanks. I'm editing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are few steps to increase performance:

Note, I am assuming you want in place solution.

1) Sort your TreeMap based on value. It will help you to stop the iteration (Later steps you will understand). O(n logn)

2) Create a temp variable which will store start/last processed element.

3) start Iteration and check for every value. In this case, inner loop will be there which will give next value and add it to with previous entry value, if outer loop values matches. at every iteration inner loop value remove it from iterator, so it will remove from treemap and will be part of value of same action.

4) It's done now, your map will have all the value as a output.

Note, iterator with two loops (outer and inner) will take O(n) times. So your worst case solutions is with O(n log n).